# Ubuntu 13.04 problem with desktop

Tags: unity

I have encountered a very interesting problem. Whenever I start up my Ubuntu (Unity):

- right-clicking on the desktop (wallpaper) doesn't do **anything**
- pressing the Win key (to bring up the dash) doesn't do **anything**
- left clicking on the Ubuntu icon on the left-bar brings up dash allowing to start programs normally
- if I have **one** program opened and click on **minimize** button, the application seemingly freezes
- the only way I found to 'unfreeze' the application is to try performing another action; sometimes I need to switch to different run-level, sometimes just using the shortcut to start terminal etc...

I tried looking at the log files (syslog, xorg.log, kern.log) but haven't found anything suspicious - certainly no error messages.

Are there any troubleshooting steps you guys could recommend? I haven't tried Gnome or different desktop environment (I do want to find out what is going on). Thanks in advance for any help / suggestion!

Comment: Any more details about your computer hardware?

Comment: I don't think it's all that relevant (since it had worked before on different ubuntu installation). It seems it could be something with the drivers perhaps? It's got 2 graphics cards (integrated one with Sandy Bridge core i7 & discrete Radeon 6850), but I'm only using the Intel one (with the latest Intel driver) - it did not happen with the installation of that driver but it hasn't disapppeared.